# How make puppet install postgresql in the given address

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I have a postgresql database cluster with one master and one standby node, I want to setup the puppet module for only configuring the database nodes and not installing postgresql, but the problem is that if I run the 'puppet agent -t' command, puppet will try to install a new postgresql in '/var/lib/pgsql/postgresql-10.21/' while my current database is installed in 'var/lib/pgsql'.

So my question is that how to force puppet to use /var/lib/pgsql as the correct directory and not try to install a new postgresql database?

I removed this part which is for installing the database in puppet module:

```
  postgresql::server::db { 'mydb':
   user     => 'dbuser',
   password => postgresql_password('dbuser', hiera('mydb_pass')),
   grant    => 'all',
   encoding => 'UNICODE',
   locale   => 'C',
   }
```

but I still get this error messages by running 'sudo puppet agent -t --noop':

```
symlink_realpath(/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql-10.21) realpath() failed: No such file or directory
symlink_realpath(/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql-10.21) realpath() failed: No such file or directory
symlink_realpath(/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql-10.21) realpath() failed: No such file or directory
symlink_realpath(/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql-10.21) realpath() failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the puppetlabs/posgresql package.  It's not immediately clear to me why the code presented would cause the software installation status to be managed at all, but if it *is* managed then this module will do that via the appropriate package from the distro.  The installation path is built in that, not accessible beforehand by Puppet.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for your answer, yes I'm using puppetlabs/posgresql package as you said, can you help me understand how to give puppet the correvt '/var/lib/pgsql' path and force it to use this address?

Comment: You have not understood the key point of my comment, which is that *Puppet is not deciding* where Postgres goes.  If anything, it is deciding whether to install your distribution's PostgreSQL package (i.e. an RPM, DEB, or similar), and the destination path is determined by that package.  This is controlled by the curators of the distribution.

Comment: I suspect that the code presented is not sufficient to reproduce the behavior -- that is, I don't think that declaring a `Postgres::Server::Db` instance will automatically cause Puppet to manage installation of postgres, although I am not confident in that assessment.  Even if it is not actually performing an install, however, the module may well assume that installation was performed via the distro's package.